# Why is rounding not a solution to the floating point determinism problem?

Tags: javascript, networking, floating-point, game-physics, deterministic

I'm looking to make a deterministic networked game and everywhere online there are stories about how floating point math isn't deterministic and will often give different results on different computers, architectures, processors, browsers, etc.

One reason for this is because some processors may do math with 80-bit precision (x87 I think?) and then truncate down to 64 bits for the final result.

Then, if you read these posts, people always mention either doing all math with integers, using very slow fixed point math libraries, or rewriting entire math libraries to be deterministic.

But, I'm confused. For all the math in my game, I don't really care if my floating point has 5 decimals of precision vs 15. So why isn't a solution to this problem just rounding?

That is, whenever you do an operation on floating points, apply this function to the result:

```
function round(n) {
  return Math.truncate(n * 100000) / 100000;
}
```

It doesn't really matter to me that this makes my floats less precise. I don't really need insane levels of precision anyway. But doesn't this fix the problem of floating point determinism? Because while different processors might have *slightly* different results on math functions, none of them will be *that* far off, no? So if we simply round the result to 6 decimal places with the above function, shouldn't all architectures give the same results?

And then you don't have to rewrite your entire math library or use extremely slow fixed point operators everywhere. Marking this as Javascript because I only really care as this relates to Javascript personally, although it is a bit language agnostic.

Comment: This does not work because sometime where will be a result for which `n * 100000` is at or above an integer in one system and slightly below that integer in another system. Then `Math.truncate` will produce different results for them, and then `Math.truncate(n * 100000) / 100000` has made the two results even farther apart than they were before the rounding operation.

Comment: Oh, well, what about rounding instead of truncating then? Then `1.8` and `2.2` would both go to 2, no?

Comment: Rounding to nearest has the same issue as rounding toward zero. With any rounding method, there are points where numbers on one side of the point round to one number and numbers on the other side round to a different number.

Comment: Ahhhh, you're right! Drats. Is there any way to salvage it? To perform floating point operations with less precision? Such that they will have the same results on all machines?

Comment: @RyanPeschel The issue applies to all sorts of precision types.  Using different types might change the rate differences occur, yet they still occur.  An alternative is to make your FP code more resilient to small changes.  To do that requires details of the task at hand.